# How to read data from text fields in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How do I output a formatted text using php. I'm storing it in a field will longtext data type. I save the data using the code below:

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['x']);
    $db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_codes SET code='$code'");
}
?>
```

But when I try to retrieve it:

```
<?php echo htmlentities($yo); ?>
```

It's not already formatted. And if I don't use the htmlentities function, I don't see any output. Please help

Comment: Can we see the query used to get $yo? And some sample I/O?

Comment: seems like I only needed the <pre>..</pre> tags. @nachito: $yo comes from this: <?php $yo = $db->get_var("SELECT code FROM tbl_codes WHERE id=0"); ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) says, `htmlentities` will convert chars like '`<`' and '`>`' in '`&lt;`' and '`&gt;`' thus the html tags will have no effect. For example, if you have bolded text like this:

```
<b>example</b>
```

it will be converted in:

```
&lt;b&gt;example&lt;/b&gt;
```

Since in your last comment you write that you only need the `<pre>` tag, you can consider the possibility to use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) like:

```
$cleanOutput = strip_tags($yo, '<pre>');
```